# Finding periods for $x_{i+1}=(7x_i+b)\, \operatorname{mod} 30$

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics

Let $x_{i+1}=(7x_i+b)\, \operatorname{mod} 30$ be an LCG. For which $b\in \{0,1,2,...,29\}$ are there $x_0$ with orbits of length $2$?

**My attempt**

I know the term "orbits" from group actions, but I guess here it means $x_{i+2}=x_i \, \operatorname{mod} 30$ for all $i$?

I know that for $x_{n+1}=(ax_n+b)\, \operatorname{mod} m $, we have:

- $ x_{n}=\left(a^{n} x_{0}+\frac{a^{n}-1}{a-1} b\right) \bmod m $
- $ x_{n+k}=\left(a^{k} x_{n}+\frac{a^{k}-1}{a-1} b\right) \bmod m $

So, plugging it in:

- $x_i=7^ix_0+\frac{7^i-1}{6}b \bmod{30}$
- $x_{i+2}=49x_i+8b \, \bmod{30}=19x_i+8b\bmod{30}$

Equating the coefficients yields $7^ix_0=49x_i$ and $\frac{7^i-1}{6}=8$. From the latter equation, I get $i=2$, that means $x_0=x_2$. Does this lead me anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want $x_2\equiv x_0\pmod{30}.$  Since $x_2 = 49x_0+8b$ then $18x_0 + 8b\equiv 0 \pmod {30}$

As $\gcd(30,18) = 6$ it is only possible if $6|8b$ as well, in which case there will exist an $x_0$ that does what you need it to do.

Comment: Is there a way to know what periods an lcg will produce?